# cannot to Unzip PASSWORD PROTECTED file using Batch Script via 7Zip?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, server, angular-promise, 7zip

I am trying to unzip a password-protected file with no success.
The server always returns 'success' for an unknown reason Even though the code does not work for me, the unzip action is probably has a problem and therefore can not perform the action.

From the **import** function i call

```
function _import(packagePath, folderUnzippingTo, element) {
        DataFolder.createFolder(_PACKAGES_FOLDER + folderUnzippingTo, true). 
            then(
            function (success) {
                passwordDialog(packagePath) //// to open pass file
                    .then(
                    function (success) {
                      function (err) {
                                console.log("unzip ERROR");
                            });
                    },
                    function (err) {
                        console.log("Enter wrong password");
                    });
            });
    }
```

And then creates two promises.
As soon as I activate the function I create a dialog and pass the password to the controller that calls the server, and the promises have to go backץ

server side:

```
function _openPassword(req, res) { //always returns success with pass object
    var filePath = req.body.filePath,
        password = req.body.password;
    var sevenZip = path.resolve(__dirname + "\\..\\..\\..\\7z.exe");

    var child = spawn(sevenZip, ["x", filePath.trim(), "-p" + password]);

    child.stdout.on('data', (data) => { });
    child.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log(data.toString());
        res.status(500).send("file: " + filename.trim() + "\noutput folder: " + outputFolder + "\n" + error);
    });

    // Unzip done
    child.on('close', (code) => {
        res.status(200).send();
    });
}
```

someone ???